How to display totals vertically on stacked bar chart?
I have a stacked bar chart and need the total values at the top to display vertically. If I turn on data labels it displays the value of each stack and you can rotate them vertically, but I just need the total value to display vertically and there isn't an option to do so. Anyone have any ideas?

I tried turning on data values, but I just need the total.

You can turn on Total Labels, but you cannot rotate them. The labels will overlap and get cut off.
If you need full visibility of the total labels, you may want to use a horizontal bar chart instead.

If that doesn't do what you need, you could check out 3rd party custom visuals like Charticulator or Deneb, which offer features that go beyond what the built-in Power BI charts can do.
